# What is the difference between "je voudrais faire" and "je ferais"?

Tags: usage, conditionnel

I am trying to figure out how to say "I don't know what I would do" in French. But, I have been getting two different answers as to how to say "I would do". I read that you're supposed to use the conditionnel mood when trying to express something like this. However, someone else told me that you're supposed to say "je voudrais faire" instead of "je ferais".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Je ferais* = I would do

*Je voudrais faire* = I would like to do

Answer (score 1):

Je ne sais pas **ce que je ferais** si mon chat tombait malade.

I don't know **what I would do** if my cat got sick.

It's very simple. In this case, the would do, a conditional in English is also the conditional in French.

Otherwise, /**I would like to go up to Paris for the day**/ would be: **J'aimerais aller à Paris** pour la journée or **Je voudrais aller à Paris pour la journée.**

Answer (score 0):

**Je ferais** is when you will do something, and **je voudrais faire** is when you want to do something else.

Comment: Welcome to French Language Alex. Your answer is not  correct. *Je ferais* is the [conditional tense](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/french/grammar/verbsh/conditionalrev1.shtml) to be used when expressing  what **would** happen.  Not to be confused with *je ferai*, [future tense](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/french/grammar/verbsh/futuretensehirev1.shtml) to express what **will** happen. Hope to see you again on French Language.